# how to transfer the date in view?

Tags: python, django

please help to solve the problem.
model:

```
class Diary(models.Model):
    .........................
    date = models.DateField(
        'Дата записи',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )                       
    last_edit_date = models.DateTimeField(
        'Дата последнего редактирования',
        auto_now=True,
    )       

    @classmethod
    def get_entry_public(self, id_record):
        return self.objects.get(id=id_record, is_active=True, is_delete=False)
```

view:

```
def record(request, id_record): 
    entry = Diary.get_entry_public(id_record=id_record)
    print(entry.date)
    print(entry.last_edit_date)

    return HttpResponse(....)
```

I'm trying to pass the value of the field

> ```
> last_edit_date
> ```

in view. but

> ```
> print(entry.last_edit_date)
> ```

outputs

> ```
> None
> ```

[db](http://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=e7780851b9664f33989adb78cbac9810)

Comment: Your method get_public_entry takes an argument, not a keyword argument. Maybe you should try: `entry = Diary.get_entry_public(id_record)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
entry = Diary.objects.get(pk=id_record)
```

*get_entry_public* is a method of data record, not data table

**update** (thanks to cesar)

```
entry = Diary.objects.get(pk=id_record, is_active=True, is_delete=False)
```

You can use this code in your view, or you can extend the Diary manager with it, but in Diary class methods you are already in ONE Diary record

Comment: I think he wants to get a certain record only if it is active and not deleted. Your code returns a record with a given ID without taking care of those constraints.

Comment: Yes, my example is too short. It can be   entry = Diary.objects.get(pk=id_record,  is_active=True, is_delete=False)

Comment: If you extend the above statement to: `entry = Diary.objects.get(pk=id_record, is_active=True, is_delete=False)` then the classmethod get_entry_public becomes obsolete. EDIT: we were typing simultaneously.